# 1948 Kitchen ceiling exhaust fan?

Tags: exhaust-fan

Our house was built in 1948. There is a Fasco ceiling exhaust fan that we want to replace.
However, looking and feeling into the housing of the fan, it seems as if it is totally enclosed.
Where is this exhausting to? Is it possible there is no duct?
There is not an opening on the outside of the house.
[image]

Comment: Attic or additional floor above?

Comment: The only way to know for sure is to remove it and see what's back there. If you're not finding an exhaust on the exterior of the house, though, then there's a pretty good chance it's just exhausting into the wall, ceiling or attic.